# HTML Email Responsive Font Size Not Rendering on Gmail

Tags: html, email, responsive-design, outlook, gmail

All:

Please see the below screen shots and help me understand why Gmail is rendering the type significantly smaller than outlook...

https://ibb.co/d4u0Ec

https://ibb.co/h2KYZc

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){
    #templateColumns{
        width:100% !important;
    }
    .mobile-hidden{
        display: none!important;
    }
    .templateColumnContainer{
        display:block !important;
        width:100% !important;
    }

    .columnImage{
        height:auto !important;
        max-width:480px !important;
        width:100% !important;
        text-align: center!important;
    }

    .leftColumnContent{
        font-size:16px !important;
        line-height:125% !important;
    }

    .rightColumnContent{
        font-size:16px !important;
        line-height:125% !important;
    }
    .mobile-short{
    height: 40px!important;
    }
}


                <tr>
                <td class="leftColumnContent" align="left" style="font-family:Georgia, Helvetica, Arial; font-size:14px; color:#3d3d3d;line-height:24px!important;">
                    We want you to love your boots as much as we do. We offer free shipping and returns so you can try them on at home.
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Could you please post all of your html code? It's hard to determine from what you posted to see the issue is and possibly help you.

Comment: try this media query to see if it works: `@media only screen and (max-width:480px){`. Gmail is very particular about how CSS is written.